# Need an optimised and efficient query

Tags: sql, query-optimization

```
PID UID Req Res

1   101 C   to
2   101 A   from
3   101 B   to
4   102 A   from
5   102 B   from
```

I want to write a query to get all the records from table which satisfies the below condition.

I want to get UID of all the records where Res='to'. For these particular UID I want to get records with Req='A'. I wrote a sample query and it worked also. Please find the query below.

```
SELECT Res,
       UID,
       Req
FROM   TABLE
WHERE  Req = 'A'
       AND UID = (SELECT DISTINCT( UID )
                  FROM   TABLE
                  WHERE  Res = 'to')
```

The problem with the above query is that while running in SQL server 2008, it is running for more than one hour for fetching just 15-20 records. Total number of records is big as this is a production table. I wish to know why the query is long running as well as whether I can get an optimized query for the same.

Thanks,
Prabhath

Comment: Please provide table structure including indexes and the execution plan.

Comment: Your sample query doesn't work... if should raise an error unless your table is unique on `res` as you're checking whether a single `uid` is equal to many.

Comment: Also, am I missing something really obvious or is the answer `select * from table where req = 'A' and res = 'to'`?

Comment: Thanks Ben. Your query will fetch only records with Res='to'and  Req='A'. I need all records with Req='A' and its UID should be one from the set of UIDs fetched from all records with Res='to'. In short if Res='to' for a record its UID can be considered. For that particular UID if Req='A', That record should be displayed.

Comment: Maybe the OP is using a DB that supports such a construct. But the DB agnostic form should be `AND UID IN (SELECT....)`

Comment: @dbenham: There is no such construct, in no DBMS. Your `IN` is the correct use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your query is so slow is that your engine is probably running that subquery for *every single row it considers*, and that query may be an implicitly aggregating (since it uses DISTINCT). That's a lot of work to do for each row, and as it gets later into the result set, it is likely doing plenty of swapping to make it happen.

This query joins the table to itself on the condition that the joined row has the same UID *and* has Res = 'to'. Rows are filtered based on two factors: having at least one matching row with same UID and Res='to', and having Req='A'.

This will be a very fast solution, and here's why: Query engines are optimized to eliminate rows from the result set as soon as they can. For rows PID=1, 3, &5, the engine will immediately discard them from consideration  (not even perform the join) since Req != 'A'. For row PID=2, the join will match row 1 and then *usually* not even continue on to join 3 (since it knows via the DISTINCT keyword (and the fact that no columns from the join are being selected) that matching additional rows in the join would not change the result set). And for PID=4, it won't match any.

```
SELECT DISTINCT main_row.Res,
       main_row.UID,
       main_row.Req
FROM   TABLE AS main_row
JOIN   TABLE AS res_join 
       ON main_row.UID = res_join.UID 
       AND res_join.Res = 'to'
WHERE  main_row.Req = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `JOIN` instead of a subquery:

```
SELECT a.Res,
       a.UID,
       a.Req
  FROM TABLE a
  JOIN (SELECT UID FROM TABLE WHERE Res = 'to' GROUP BY UID) b
       ON a.UID = b.UID
 WHERE a.Req = 'A'
```

Comment: (This is not equivalent) but why would it be more efficient?

Comment: @Zane Bien : Thanks for your query. I will try this and get back to you. But why we are using a join to fetch records from a unique table.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen other posts that suggest that the following might be more efficient:

```
SELECT Res, UID, Req
FROM TABLE t
WHERE  Req = 'A' and
       exists (select * from table t2 where t2.res = 'to' and t.uid = t2.uid)
```

Logically, it does the same thing but the correlated subquery might produce a better query plan in this case.

It also depends on who selective Req and Res are (are there many rows involved or just a few).  If many rows in the table satisfy the conditions, then there are alternative formulations using windows functions.

Comment: `GROUP BY t2.uid HAVING count(1) = 1` could added to the inner query to sort of mirror the original query's `UID = (SELECT DISTINCT ...` semantic. Of course there's a big difference between an error and not returning a row.

Comment: And I'm specifically leaving out those constructs.  the point is that the exists with the correlated subquery does what the original query does.  You run the danger by including a group by or distinct that the optimizer will choose a different path.

Comment: Actually I meant to end that comment with a thought on the original point of optimization and how it might revert back to a bad plan. I agree that your query is a good choice but thought the subtle semantic difference was worth noting. Of course I think `SELECT DISTINCT` was probably employed to collapse multiple, _identical_ values into a scalar result. Just the minimal change to `SELECT MIN(t2.UID)` or `GROUP BY t2.UID` is probably a better choice and possibly a better plan too. `HAVING` isn't even relevant most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Since it may just be your use of DISTINCT that's causing the problem, these are worth exploring. Obviously they are quite close to your original form.

```
SELECT Res, UID, Req FROM TABLE
WHERE  Req = 'A'
    AND UID = (SELECT t2.UID FROM TABLE as t2 WHERE Res = 'to' GROUP BY t2.UID)

SELECT Res, UID, Req FROM TABLE
WHERE  Req = 'A'
    AND UID = (SELECT MIN(t2.UID) FROM TABLE as t2 WHERE Res = 'to')
```